# Synchronization in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, mutex

How can i synchronize these 9 threads so that they execute before main thread?

I want to check validity of rows in a 2D array of size 9. Each row should contain values(1 to 9).
For that i created a thread named as "void* checkingRows(void* arg)" in the main thread and joined it with main.
Then thread checkingRows is creating further 9 threads which are checking validity of each row.

`````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````
Pthread_t id1;
pthread_mutex_t mut1;
int arr[9][9] = {  
                    {6,2,4,5,3,9,1,8,7},
                    {6,6,9,7,2,8,6,3,4},
                    {8,3,7,6,1,4,2,9,5},
                    {1,4,3,8,6,5,7,2,9},
                    {9,5,8,2,4,7,3,6,1},
                    {7,6,2,3,9,1,4,5,8},
                    {3,7,1,9,5,6,8,4,2},
                    {4,9,6,1,8,2,5,7,3},
                    {2,8,5,4,7,3,9,1,6}
                };
````````````````````````````````````
void* rowCheck(void* arg){
    int* argument = (int*) arg;
    int idx = *argument;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        int temp = arr[idx][i];
        count = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < 9; j++){
            if(arr[idx][j] == temp || arr[idx][j] <= 0 || arr[idx][j] >= 10){
                count++; 
            }
            if(count > 1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
                count = 0;
                cout<<"ERROR at"<<arr[idx][j]<<endl;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

````````````````````````````````````
void* checkingRows(void* arg){
    int *row = new int;
    *row = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<gridSize; i++){
        pthread_create(&workerIdRow[i], NULL, &rowCheck, row);
        *row = *row + 1;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
`````````````````````````````````
int main(){

    pthread_mutex_init(&mut1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &checkingRows, NULL);
    pthread_join(id1,NULL);

    retrun 0;

}
````````````````````````````````````

ERROR at 6
ERROR at 6
`````````````````````````````````````

Comment: The use of `new int` and `cout` indicates this is C++, not C.

Comment: Note that in `pthread_create(..., &rowCheck, row);` row is a pointer and you pass every thread the same pointer, independent if the value of the int pointed to.

Comment: Rather than using pthreads, I suggest that you have a look at [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which is the portable, built-in threading library…

Comment: You have `retrun` in `main` (instead of `return`)

Comment: I given you two proposals to solve the problems, see my answer

Comment: What sense is there in calling `pthread_join(id1,NULL)` immediately after calling `pthread_create(&id1,NULL,&checkingRows,NULL)`? Why don't you simply call `checkintRows(NULL)` at that point instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first created thread is useless because you create it and immediately waits for its end

On the contrary you do not wait for the end of the 9 other threads, so you exit before their end

When you start the sub threads you do not have a synchronization to be sure they have time to read the row number before to modify it for the next thread, several can check the same row. For that you can use a condition (still using C thread lib), or you can give each time a newly created *int* given the index.

You have a memory leak because you do not delete the *int*, and in fact it is useless to allocate it in the heap in your case

---

A proposal from your code, as you can see I directly give the address of the concerned row to each thread, I removed the intermediate thread and I wait for the end of the 9 threads, more some other changes

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mut1;

int arr[9][9] = {  
                    {6,2,4,5,3,9,1,8,7},
                    {6,6,9,7,2,8,6,3,4},
                    {8,3,7,6,1,4,2,9,5},
                    {1,4,3,8,6,5,7,2,9},
                    {9,5,8,2,4,7,3,6,1},
                    {7,6,2,3,9,1,4,5,8},
                    {3,7,1,9,5,6,8,4,2},
                    {4,9,6,1,8,2,5,7,3},
                    {2,8,5,4,7,3,9,1,6}
                };

void * rowCheck(void* arg)
{
    int * row = (int *) arg;
    const char * result = "ok";

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      int temp = row[i];
      int count = 0;

      for(int j = i; j < 9; j++){
        if(row[j] == temp || row[j] <= 0 || row[j] >= 10){
          count++; 
        }
        if(count > 1){
          result = "ko";
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
          std::cout<<"ERROR at "<< row[j]
            << " (row " << (row - arr[0])/9
              << " column " << j << ")" << std::endl;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *) result);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t id[9];

  pthread_mutex_init(&mut1, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
    if (pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, &rowCheck, arr[i]) != 0) {
      std::cerr << "error when creating thread " << i << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
    void * retval;

    pthread_join(id[i], &retval);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    std::cout << i << ":" << (char *) retval << std::endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc -lpthread
/tmp % ./a.out
ERROR at 6 (row 1 column 1)
ERROR at 6 (row 1 column 6)
0:ok
1:ko
2:ok
3:ok
4:ok
5:ok
6:ok
7:ok
8:ok
```

---

An other way is to give the index through an allocated *int* dedicated to each thread (and deleting it in the thread) :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mut1;

int arr[9][9] = {  
                    {6,2,4,5,3,9,1,8,7},
                    {6,6,9,7,2,8,6,3,4},
                    {8,3,7,6,1,4,2,9,5},
                    {1,4,3,8,6,5,7,2,9},
                    {9,5,8,2,4,7,3,6,1},
                    {7,6,2,3,9,1,4,5,8},
                    {3,7,1,9,5,6,8,4,2},
                    {4,9,6,1,8,2,5,7,3},
                    {2,8,5,4,7,3,9,1,6}
                };

void * rowCheck(void* arg)
{
    int rowNum = *((int*) arg);

    delete (int*) arg;

    int * row = arr[rowNum];
    const char * result = "ok";

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      int temp = row[i];
      int count = 0;

      for(int j = i; j < 9; j++){
        if(row[j] == temp || row[j] <= 0 || row[j] >= 10){
          count++; 
        }
        if(count > 1){
          result = "ko";
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
          std::cout<<"ERROR at "<< row[j]
            << " (row " << rowNum
              << " column " << j << ")" << std::endl;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *) result);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t id[9];

  pthread_mutex_init(&mut1, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
    if (pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, &rowCheck, new int(i)) != 0) {
      std::cerr << "error when creating thread " << i << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
    void * retval;

    pthread_join(id[i], &retval);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    std::cout << i << ":" << (char *) retval << std::endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You ask,

> How can i synchronize these 9 threads so that they execute before main
>   thread?

, and I think you're talking about these:

> checkingRows is creating further 9 threads which are
>   checking validity of each row.

Of course, these can't run before `main()`, at least not before `main` *starts*, unless you start them in that time frame.  You don't.  But I think what you're really after is just that that they *finish* before `main` runs past a certain point.

Well that's what `pthread_join` is for.  I see you're already using that function in `main()` for the thread it launches, but perhaps you are confused by the fact that that does not affect the additional threads started by the second one.

It just doesn't automatically work that way.  Once started, threads run independently of each other.  If you want to wait for a thread to finish, then you must join that specific thread.  In your case, that probably means that  `checkingRows()` should join each thread it starts before it itself terminates.